# Boot Windows 7 with UEFI

Tags: windows-7, boot, 64-bit, uefi

I am trying to install Windows 7 x64 SP1 on a UEFI enabled Dell 6430 laptop (yes, I know I can set legacy options, but I specifically need a UEFI image for capture) and the installation disc stops at the Starting Windows screen.  I have used a standard Windows 7 x64 SP1 Enterprise disc, the Dell installation disc it came with, and a custom-built WinPE 3.1 preloaded with hard drive drivers and none will boot past this point.  If I use a Windows 8 disc or a WinPE 4 environment it makes it just fine.  This is not specific to this machine, all of this model are doing this as well as several other models.  What am I missing to make this work?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, secure boot is disabled.

Comment: Updated with 64bit and tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with my Dell 15R SE.

I had to go to the `UEFI` with <kbd>F2</kbd> and set the option `Load Legacy Option ROM` to `true`.

Now Windows 7 still uses UEFI, but UEFI loads the old VGA BIOS ROM which allows the installation of older Operating systems like Windows 7. If you don't enable this, the new UEFI graphic protocol GOP is used and Win7 doesn't support this and hangs at the Starting Windows logo.